# Delete [jason] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason) tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason) appears to be a misspelling of [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json). I therefore suggest that this tag be deleted. Questions currently tagged with this should be retagged with [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json).

Comment: It looks like `jason` is correct for this  question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902106/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-a-no-failure-event-was-generated-for-warning-er, it is not related to `json`.

Comment: Perhaps this one too then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821632/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-literal-in-agentspeak.

Comment: It may be that the tag wiki for [tag:jason] should make its purpose clear, and indicate that it is not related to [tag:json]?

Comment: Yes these are about [Jason](http://jason.sourceforge.net/wp/). Someone should either write a tag-wiki, or replace the `jason` tag to something that people won't use incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I retagged the questions about JSON that were erroneously tagged [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason).

However, the [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason) tag is a valid tag, and it is correctly applied to at least two questions:

- [Is there a way to 'suppress' a 'No failure event was generated for..' warning/error in Jason/AgentSpeak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902106/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-a-no-failure-event-was-generated-for-warning-er)
- [How to get the value of a literal in Agentspeak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821632/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-literal-in-agentspeak)

I recommend that someone write a tag wiki (or at least an excerpt) explaining the actual purpose of the [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason) tag.

Comment: Would it be worth it to retag the current Jason questions as `jason-lang` or something in that vein, and then make `jason` a synonym of `json`? Note that I had not heard of Jason until today, so if I'm grievously offending a horde of Jason users, I apologize.

Comment: I thought about making [jason] a synonym of [json], but resisted the urge because it's just *wrong*. [jason-lang] doesn't make sense, because it's not a language...

Comment: Well, someone "addressed" your concerns by hijacking the tag for a different obscure use case. The two particular example questions are damaged now, retagged as JSON which they aren't, done by rather high-level users. Posted another round as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411001/burninate-jason