# Burninate [jason]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

While it's not a widely used tag (it has 44 hits right now), [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason) ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jason/info)) displays an impressive 10:1 mistake:correct usage ratio. As one can probably guess, it's slapped on various JSON-related questions for negligent reasons: its pronunciation sounds fine for those who don't know what JSON is, perhaps autocompletion as "jason" does precede "json" in alphabetical order, or whatever else.

Q&A from [Criteria for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7916438):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
Not at all. By its description, [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jason) should refer to a specific JSON-parsing library for Elixir, but in reality 10 cases out of 11 will lead to Java, C#, PHP and Python questions when seeing this tag.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
Well, probably yes.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
Only could. Current usage clearly does not.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
Well, yes, in common contexts it simply means a typo'd "JSON". For -at least some- Elixir folks it presumably means the given library of course, and searching for it as text shows that [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560239/how-to-add-rules-in-jason-while-running) is an actual (or implementation of a?) language for agent-oriented programming.

---

**Added fun**: I just noticed [Delete [jason] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396414/delete-jason-tag) from a year ago, concluding that it has legit uses and someone should create the tag wiki. But, it concluded that with the AI/agent-oriented usage in mind, citing two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902106/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-a-no-failure-event-was-generated-for-warning-er), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821632/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-literal-in-agentspeak)) as legit usages. Now those two questions are retagged as JSON which they have nothing to do with, by experienced 89k and 683k users, the latter damaging the title too, that's how bad this tag is. It may be fit for multiple obscure use cases, but actually thrives as a typo in practice.

Comment: These burnination questions assume _correct_ usage. I'd say that the tad _does_ describe the contents of the questions, _is_ unambiguous, on-topic and meaningful. If it's misused, then that should be fixed.

Comment: If it's for a specific library and that library is relatively uncommon then perhaps [tag:Elixir-Jason] would make more sense, so you can still have the tag, and hopefully(?) the intellisense would still bring it up for typing jason, but stop newbies from using it instead of [tag:Json]

Comment: Typing (any part of) "Json" [doesn't give Jason as a tag hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZPTs.png)

Comment: You're looking for a [tag:retag-request], not a burnination

Comment: I don't think that *burnination* is the right action here. There are already less than 50 questions, and after retagging the obvious misused ones we are left with only a handful of valid questions. If anything, the tag should be simply renamed. Also, there is no pun in the title so this is not a valid request (just kidding!)

Comment: Since when do we burninate tags because they are on-topic but users misuse them? Should we also burninate Java and JavaScript tags because they are so often tagged on the opposing language?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's obvious people are neither reading the excerpt, nor paying attention to what tag they are adding (many misuses had people adding other JSON tags and even JSON functions).

After cleaning the tag, I renamed it to [elixir-jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir-jason)

Answer (score 10):

From the criteria for burnination:

> A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination.

The tag is supposed to be used for questions about a specific JSON-parsing library named Jason, which is on-topic for the site, and there are (some) questions using it for that purpose. Perhaps instead of burninating the tag, it should be renamed `elixir-jason` to prevent misuse, and the few dozen questions misusing the tag can be edited.

Comment: I know that the community wiki says this, but it's not true in practice. If you make a tag like `unicorns` and describe it as *"a mythical creature taking form of a horse with a horn above its eyes"*, you have an unambiguous tag that has nothing to do with the site and should be removed (or point it to unicornjs maybe).

Comment: @ConnorLow Yes, if the concept described by the tag is not on-topic then it would fail that criterion, whereas if it is on-topic then it passes that criterion. I'm not sure what your point is. It's hard to see how your `unicorns` tag would not fail all four criteria.

Comment: My point is not every tag burnination has to pass all the tests in practice, even if the criteria says so. Passing the off-topic criteria should *usually* trump failing the unambiguous criteria for deletion.

Comment: @ConnorLow but the tag *is* on-topic. Being misused doesn't warrant burnination - at best cleanup and renaming (as it happened here).

Comment: If a tag is on-topic but ambiguous, it can be made unambiguous (perhaps by splitting into multiple tags), and that should be better than just deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this has already been done, but in principal at least this tag unambiguously identifies a specific programming topic, so it's really not a good candidate for outright removal.

The fact that a tag is widely misused is an argument in favor of cleaning up (and possibly renaming) the tag (which is what @Machavity did), not removing it entirely. There are lots of tags that are widely misused (such as most of the IDE tags), but I really don't think that it would be appropriate to burninate all of the IDE tags too.

Comment: It wasn't that "unambiguously", there was a clash between https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgentSpeak which was its use until around a year ago, and then came the Elixir stuff. The old usage is either lost or at least merged into [tag:agent], but Agent(Speak) seems to be the language and Jason an implementation of it, so it's kind of a [tag:C] and [tag:GCC] relation.